# Doctrine2 strictly trying to inser t NULL when i use one-to-one and many-to-one relations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

**Places.yml**

```
manyToOne:
  excursions:
    targetEntity: Excursions
    inversedBy: places
    inverse: true
    cascade: ["ALL"]
    nullable: false
    joinColumn:
      name: idx
      referencedColumnName: place_id
```

**Excursions.yml**

```
oneToOne:
  places:
    targetEntity: Places
    mappedBy: excursions
```

Excursion has one place_id. so `$exccursion->getPlaces()` returns ONE row only.

Now, when i trying to insert a value to the `Places` table, Doctrine2 says `Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "idx" violates not-null constraint`

I have no idea why this is happening. If i remove `manyToOne` then insert works. But this time `getPlaces()` is not working.

**UPDATE**

The probloem is, i use mappedBy against the database. I should only do this:

**Places.yml**

```
manyToOne:
  --remove--
```

**Excursions.yml**

```
oneToOne:
  places:
    targetEntity: Places
    joinColumn:
        name: place_id
        referencedColumnName: idx
```

This solves the problem. But i found this by trying/playing randomly. So, i don't know why :) Anyone knows that please `explain` me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the mapping is incorrect. You should not have `ManyToOne` in `Places.yml` and the inversed side mapped as `OneToOne` in `Excursions.yml`. This is most likely why you run in to those errors.
Also you want an `Excursion` to have one `Places` object linked to it but `Places` could have more `Excursions` objects if i understand your question right. So you mapping should look like this:

```
# Places.yml
OneToMany:
    excursions:
        tagertEntity: Excursions
        mappedBy: places
```

And

```
# Excursions.yml
ManyToOne:
    places:
        targetEntity: Places
        inversedBy: excursions
        joinColumn:
            name: places_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Note that:

1. The `ManyToOne` relationship should be inside the entity having only 1 of the other
2. The `OneToMany` relationship should be inside the entity having multiple objects of the other
3. `joinColumn: name:` should have the name of the column that you want created in the database
4. `joinColumn: referencedColumnName:` should have the field from the target entity that you want to use to map the relationship with (I recommend you to use id as it is unique)

After you created this mapping run the following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BUNDLE_PREFIX
```

Were `BUNDLE_PREFIX` would be the first part of you bundles name. This will generate all the correct getters and setters. Don't forget to update you database schema too:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

As some last advise I recommend (except if you intended it to be this way) you to change your entity names to `Excursion` and `Place` as each object should hold only 1 place or excursion.